# Is this a Confectionery Ganache frame?

Tags: baking

[image: Unknown baking frame]

I have been trying to search for this device for days. I’ve used the terms “dough rolling frame, caramel ruler, confectionery frame, ganache frame, adjustable ganache frame, dough leveling frame, confectionery bars/rulers” and nothing comes up.

Is there another name for this thing that will help me find it? I'm specifically looking for a frame that is adjustable and has those little notches in it.

[image: dough rolling frame]

After some additional searching I found something similiar but they just call it a frame >.<

Comment: When I search on Google images for "rectangular ganache frame" lots of images showing something like this pop up. Weird you didn't get those. :/ They are sold on Amazon and the like under names like "stainless steel square ganache frame". Not sure if this is exactly what you want though, because you already looked for that

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I did come across those when I searched "ganache frame" but they weren't exactly what I was looking for. The item I'm looking for is adjustable and has several notches on the side. I managed to find something similar but I still can't find the name for it. >.< The one I did find was part of a cake rolling system and it isn't sold separately unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

To me, this looks like a tart ring. In commercial kitchens, tarts are not baked in pans, they are baked in ring walls arranged on baking sheets.

The traditional rings are round (duh), but the word has stayed for the square and rectangular versions. And of course, it can be reused for purposes other than baking tarts, since the shape is convenient for many tasks.

So, look for purchasing a "rectangular tart ring" and you'll likely find what you need.